# Nextflow error in 1 process stops all other processes

Tags: linux, workflow, nextflow

When I submit a job with nextflow, one of the processes fails, there's a corrupted file. Obviously I can remove that file from the job list but I don't want this to happen in the future when I scale it up. By default this stops all the other processes (9) from running and the nextflow job finishes.

How do I stop this one failed job from affecting the others?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer after some more digging in the docs here (https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#errorstrategy). I needed to add errorStrategy 'finish' to my process

```
process ignoreAnyError {
    errorStrategy 'finish'
    script:
    <your command string here>
}
```